# How to integrate Paypal integration in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, stripe-payments

I am integrating payment module for the first time. I want to integrate `paypal` payment in my app. For this I see multiple options but I can't decide which one is better.

1) [integration with Paypal](http://railscasts.com/episodes/141-paypal-basics) (Difficult one)

2) `PayPal-Ruby-SDK`

3) [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) (Looking Easy)

Which one is better? I want to use stripe but is it support paypal ? It is available in every country?

Please guide me and don't ask to search on google. 
NOte : Better meanz easier to implement

Comment: Well if you want paypal then Stripe is out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question on 'better' is very subjective. Some facts: cost to you in time & cost in you per transaction. Depending on the country Stripe  & Paypal take different amounts. I believe (in the uk) Stripe is cheaper (https://stripe.com/gb/pricing), 1.4% + 20p compared to paypal which I believe starts at 3.4% + 20p.

However for a developer, the bigger cost is the cost to build & maintain. My subjective experience on this (having implemented both previously) is the stripes documentation is easier and faster to integrate into your app.

Please note: Stripe does not o(as far as I know) support paypal payments. If you need this, you will need to use Paypal or Braintree (a paypal company: https://www.braintreepayments.com). Braintree is an all in one payments processor (similar charges to paypal), however they are currently offering the first £30k free (it may have country restrictions on that offer).

Comment: Paypal used to be a little tricky to implement with poor (and usually out of date) implementation info, however Braintree have solved that. Braintree & Stripe are both only a few hours to implement a PoC. Stripe has alot of ruby based info, so you may want to start there.

Comment: If in future I want to integrate it with other Cards . Is it extendable?

Comment: With both providers the cards they allow are down to them, but both are expanding to accept almost everything.